# How do I add an event handler for every request in ASP.NET that will be handled by PageHandlerFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I want to configure an asp.net website so that for every request it executes my event handler(say for tracking/logging some info from request object) only if request will be handled by an `PageHandlerFactory`.

I know I can write it in `Application_BeginRequest` but that is called for every kind of request(be it *.axd or so ,Correct me if I'm wrong here). `HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler` might be null at this time so I can't put conditional logic for handler type. For some reason(legacy business rules/checks) I can't move the my logic to `Application_EndRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can try using the `httphandler and httpmodule` in asp.net

it has an event `LogRequest`

> LogRequest - Occurs just before ASP.NET performs any logging for
>   the current request. The LogRequest event is raised even if an error
>   occurs. You can provide an event handler for the LogRequest event to
>   provide custom logging for the request.

Furthure in ASP.net we have

> ASP.NET uses different HTTP handlers to serve different file types.
>   For example, the handler for web Page creates the page and control
>   objects, runs your code, and renders the final HTML. ASP.NET default
>   handlers:
>
> 1) Page Handler (.aspx) – Handles Web pages 2) User Control Handler
>   (.ascx) – Handles Web user control pages 3) Web Service Handler
>   (.asmx) – Handles Web service pages 4) Trace Handler (trace.axd) –
>   Handles trace functionality

You can get more insight at
[httphandler and httpmodule in asp.net](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2012/07/httphandler-and-httpmodule-in-aspnet.html)

Comment: Ok I'll look into it.